# What are these tiny black things on the tips of my chive seedlings?

Tags: indoors, containers, herbs, chives

I just purchased and transplanted these chive seedlings. They came from the store with these tiny hard black ovoids on about a third of the tips, although I didn't notice until I got home. What are they? Seed husks maybe?[image: Onion chive seedlings in 6 inch pot][image]

Answer (score 4):

Those are the seed coats (the protective outer coatings of the seeds). You'll notice [they look like onion seeds](https://www.superfoodevolution.com/black-onion-seeds.html). I've seen those on alliums I've grown from seed. They're nothing to worry about here. With some other kinds of plants, however, sometimes they won't let the cotyledons free (or free enough), and can stifle the plant. Chives are monocots, though; I don't know that that could be a problem here.

So, it looks like there are a lot of plants in that pot (rather than just one).

Answer (score 0):

It's the case of the seeds. When they sprout, the seed case is taken with them. Don't worry, its completely normal, they will just fall out soon, you can even take them out yourself.

Comment: That answer has already been given.